# How to check if the string in the NSarray is Changing

Tags: ios, objective-c

Its basic question but please help:-

Scenario:- I have an `NSArray {@"Bat",@"Bat",@"Bat",@"Bat"@"Ball",@"Ball",@"Cricket"}` and it will be coming from webservice, basically i want to increment the value if it is changing from Bat to ball but with one more condition that there should be at least two ball in successive

for example in above case if x=0 then  after the iteration on Nsarray the value will be 1 coz there is only one cricket if there was two successive Cricket then the value will be 2.

Let me know if question is clear or not, need help on this.
Thanks for help in advance

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you want to get in the variable x? Do you want to get how many repeated occurrences of each string are there, or do you want how many times the string change, or something else?

Comment: Do you want to increment your value as new item found, right?

Comment: @Mital Yes i want to increment  value but only if two successive same string  is found

Comment: By definition it's not changing, since NSArray and NSString are both immutable.  (Your question is not at all clear.  But if you state it clearly you will probably be able to figure out the solution yourself.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question was not very clear. I hope this is what you want.

```
NSArray *strings = @[@"Bat",@"Bat",@"Bat",@"Bat",@"Ball",@"Ball",@"Cricket",];

NSUInteger index = -1;
NSString *previousString = nil;
BOOL canIncrement = FALSE;
for (NSString *string in strings) {
    if (!previousString) {
        previousString = string;
    }else if ([previousString isEqualToString:string]){
        canIncrement = TRUE;
    }else{
        index += canIncrement?1:0;
        canIncrement = FALSE;
        previousString = string;
    }
}

index += canIncrement?1:0;

NSLog(@"Index : %d",index);
```

Comment: i checked your code to test if it work with my issue and i replace the array with NSArray *strings = @[@"Bat",@"Bat",@"Bat",@"Bat",@"Ball",@"Ball",@"Cricket",@"Cricket"]; in this case i should get value 2  as there are now two successive cricket but i dint get it, shows 1 only let me know if what needs to done

Comment: infact value should be incremented only when there are two consecutive change in string  For ex:- NSArray *strings = @[@"Bat",@"Bat",@"Bat",@"Bat",@"Ball",@"Ball",@"Cricket"]; if index=0 then the value of index will be 1 as there is only one cricket but if there was two consecutive cricket string then the value will be 2

Comment: @DAMM108 With the current code this will work. But I need more clarification to make it fail proof. What would be the index of this case @[Bat, Bat, Bat, Ball, Ball] ?

Comment: it will be 1 if index initialized as 0 coz  from string bat it is changing to ball (to increment the value there should be atleast two consecutive same string )

Comment: @DAMM108 If there is consecutive item rite from the start the first change of string should be ignored that is why i gave index as -1 to offset that. Only then all your requirement would be met. Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: ok so if you are giving -1 then the value will be 0  for this @[Bat, Bat, Bat, Ball, Ball]

Comment: @DAMM108 For that condition, index would be 1 not 0, when there is change from bat, it would 0 and at the end of array, after the loop, index would be incremented one more since the flag is true. Did you really try the updated code?

Comment: yeah i tried that ,altough thanks for the help really apreciated ,will let you know if any other problem is there

Comment: @DAMM108 I would like to know why this is not working for you?

Comment: if you can give your email id we can chat there that will be best i can explain the complete scenario :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32477/discussion-between-anupdas-and-damm108)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you turn that around and maintain an NSDictionary, with "Ball", "Bat" and "Cricket" etc. as index or key respectively and an NSNumber object as value?

Or does it have to be an array at all? 
In the end we are in an OOP environment. You could invent an Object `gear` that holds the data in a dictionary or even an array or whatever and provides methods like `addBat` or `addGear:(NSString *)gearType` or so, does the counting for your and provides accessors like `batCount` or `gearCount:(NSString*)gearType`

If you stick with the array than I fear that you will have to iterate over all strings in the array and compare them with the value that you are interested in and count the matches.